# Why does Disk Utility show "Macintosh HD" on both Logical Volume Group and the volume underneath?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, core-storage

[image]

After performing a clean install of Yosemite (erasing the entire disk using disk utility during installation), the original name of the disk (APPLE HDD HTS547575A9E384 Media) turned out to be "Macintosh HD" eventually. In addition, there are only two actions left, first aid and partition.

I have carried out clean installs several times on this MacBook Pro (13-inch, mid 2012, now running 10.10.4), but this is the first time that I encounter this kind of problem. The only thing I did was erase the entire disk. Hope to return back to its original state, showing its real name and available actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why Disk Utility does it this way is a good question, but when both the drive and volume show like this, its a CoreStorage volume.

These terminal commands should put it back to the old way if it isn't encrypted:

`diskutil cs list` - find the "Logical Volume" (not Group) and copy the long "number" at the end of the line (it looks like this: `BE1E16CA-64E2-494B-8EDC-3E843EF5C9A9`)

`diskutil cs revert BE1E…` - paste in that long string in place of BE1E…

As always, ensure you have a backup in case things don't work out.

Comment: I've tried it out, but it shows: Error: -69741: The target disk isn't eligible for reversion because it wasn't created by conversion or it is not part of a simple setup of exactly one logical and one physical volume

Comment: I think there's no hope but to erase if you want a non-CoreStorage volume. Try `diskutil cs delete` and paste the long string that's after "Logical Volume Group" in `diskutil cs list`. Disk Utility might then create a normal partition in the empty space. It might also just create a new LVG..